# Getting Weird Output While Scraping Some Tabular Data

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, html-table, puppeteer

I've created a script using `node.js` in combination with `puppeteer` to scrape some tabular data from a website. Although the data I'm after do not generate dynamically, I still used `puppeteer`.

However, when I execute my script I get the output in a single column rather than a list. Moreover, only the names are being parsed and nothing else. I gave two examples below to clarify what I meant.

***[Website link](https://fantasy.premierleague.com/player-list/)***

This is what I've tried so far:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://fantasy.premierleague.com/player-list/");
    page.waitForSelector("table.ism-table");
    const data = await page.$$("table.ism-table tbody tr");
    for (const td of data) {
      const tdata = await td.$eval("td", item => item.innerText);
      console.log(tdata);
    }
    browser.close();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Here goes the error ", e);
  }
})();
```

My current output:

```
De Gea  
Ederson 
Alisson 
Kepa    
Lloris
Cech    
Schmeichel  
Grant
```

Output I'm expecting:

```
['De Gea', 'Man Utd', '23', '£5.9']
['Ederson', 'Man City', '43', '£5.7']
['Alisson', 'Liverpool', '39', '£5.6']
['Kepa', 'Chelsea', '36', '£5.5']
['Lloris', 'Spurs', '20', '£5.4']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of [`elementHandle.$eval()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#elementhandleevalselector-pagefunction-args-1), you should be using [`elementHandle.$$eval()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#elementhandleevalselector-pagefunction-args) to obtain an array of all the `td` elements, instead of just the first element.

With `elementHandle.$$eval()`, you can then map the `innerText` into the array of `td` elements, and return the result.

```
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page    = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('https://fantasy.premierleague.com/player-list/');

    await page.waitForSelector('table.ism-table');

    const data = await page.$$('table.ism-table tbody tr');

    for (const tr of data) {
      const tdata = await tr.$$eval('td', item => item.map(e => e.innerText));
      console.log(tdata);
    }

    await browser.close();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Here goes the error ', e);
  }
})();
```

> **Note:** Make sure to use the [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) operator before [`page.waitForSelector()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options) and [`browser.close()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#browserclose), as they both return promises.

Comment: No way!!!! Incredible @Miller. A minor question about the output - I get output like `[ 'Arnautovic\t', 'West Ham\t', '37\t', '£7.0' ]`. Is there any way to kick out those `\t`'s? Thanks a zillion.

Comment: @Topto You can use `e.innerText.trim()` to remove the `\t` (horizontal tab character).